# Libreboot: Can I make ROMs on a powerful computer and then flash using RspberryPi

Tags: linux, laptop, coreboot, libreboot

I will be trying to flash LibreBoot (a particular coreboot downstream) on to a thinkpad T440p. Even with libreboot - instructions are quite complex, but look entirely doable. There is one thing, however - I cannot be sure if I can make the boot roms using `lbmk` on a relatively powerful linux computer (running manjaro/arch) and then flash using RaspberryPi, or must I make the roms on the raspberrypi that I will be using for flashing (with a SOIC-8 clip).

Intuitively I think there should be no problem, but I just don't know this area.

Perhaps someone who understands this better, or who has done libreboot flashing could explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the answer is easy enough. **Yes**. *Firstly* - as there are several distributions of coreboot (e.g. [skulls](https://github.com/merge/skulls/blob/master/t440p/README.md)) that ship pre-built roms - yes you can do that. *Secondly* - I like the quote from someone who built coreboot on their Thinkpad X230 Eric Holzbah: "Coreboot highly recommends using their patched tool chain to build coreboot roms. Don’t bother trying to build the roms on your Pi. It will take forever and oom-killer may get to it. I used make nconfig to select coreboot options. Here is my [configuration](https://www.ericholzbach.net/blog/x230_coreboot/)..."

What can I say - fiddling with Pomona clips and raspberry is quite an experience and it surely is fun and well worth it when it works :-).